# Is there a way a white-space: pre-wrap; text's next line spacing can be larger?

Tags: css

I have some text that I have using

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

It looks good but I'd like to increase the spacing for next lines in the text. Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
Hello. 
World.
```

Expected result:

```
Hello.

World.
```

Comment: @Bharadwaj: I'd like to keep the spacing the same, I'd just like to increase the space for next line. 2 next lines would be fine too.

Comment: Then you may need to place "Hello." in one container and rest of the text in another

Comment: @rotaercz Hey I am having the same problem.Can u help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. You can use `line-height`, but this will also add spacing to the top of the first line. 
You can try to alter the position of the whole block with a negative top margin and a position relative.

```
white-space: pre-wrap;                
line-height: 30px;
position: relative;
top:-15px;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Zero out your margin on the element, and put a `display: block` on it if it doesn't already have one...
Set your line-height for the whole block... 
Then set a ::first-line on it, with appropriate line-height for the space you want. Use a decimal fraction to reduce the first line height even more. See my snippet.

I prefer using `code` tags for this sort of thing since `pre` tags seem to have issues with indentation (either tabs or spaces) on the tag in the text editor, as well as inconsistencies with either larger or smaller em units.

So to control line-height when using `white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap;` you'll get consistent results (Chrome, Safari, FF, IE10) with display-blocked, margin-zero-ed `code` tags:

```css
* { margin: 0; }
  

code {
 display: inline;
 white-space: pre;
 line-height: .9em; /* doesn't work */
}
code.block {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: .9em; /*  works */
}
code.block-doubled {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: 2em; /*  works */
}
code.block-doubled::first-line {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: .9em; /*  works */
}
```

```html
<pre>
  * { margin: 0; }
 </pre>
  <code>
  code {
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: .9em; /* doesn't work */
  }
  </code>
  <code class="block">
  code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: .9em; /* works */
  }
  </code>
  <code class="block-doubled">
  code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: 2em; /* works */
  }
  </code>
```